# Ubuntu terminal: after the command appear symbols

Tags: 16.04, php7

Where i can find this symbols? (i can't run php-cs-fixer)

p.s.(ubuntu 16.04, php7.1)
[image]

Comment: I don't know what `php-cs-fixer` is supposed to do, but it is writing binary data to stdout, messing up your command line.

Comment: Can you run other commands? E.g. `ls`

Comment: @wjandrea, yes, all works fine.